# How can I redirect portals to the correct world in a Spigot/Bukkit plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, kotlin, minecraft, bukkit

I'm working on a Spigot world management plugin (a rewrite of a current one of mine) and I need to redirect nether and end portals to the correct world. I'm all done with every part of the plugin besides this one. Here are a couple examples of what I need.

If you're in the *plotworld* world and you enter a nether portal, you should go to *plotworld_nether*.

If you're in the *myworld_the_end* world and you enter the end portal to go back, you should go to *myworld*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PlayerPortalEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerPortalEvent.html), and do something like this (answering in Kotlin as you tagged it in your question):

```
@EventHandler
fun onPortalEvent(e: PlayerPortalEvent) {
    if (e.from == X) { //Where X is the location that you know the player is, use the world name or whatever you need
        e.setTo(Y) //Where Y is the location you want the TP to go to
    }
}
```

It might be enough for you.

1. Get a Portal Event
2. Verify if the `from` location is from the world/portal you want to check
3. Set the destination to wherever you want